# When is editing a question appropriate?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently made an edit which I thought was okay to do, a sort of 'cleaning-up':

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11866352

The person had written something, then added an "**EDIT:** I actually meant to do ****" at the bottom. So I removed the extra text(which can be potentially distracting) and made the necessary change. However it was rejected on the grounds of "deviates from the intent of the OP". Was it inappropriate to do? I didn't think it'd be inappropriate if the question remained the same.

Comment: My 2 cents? there are robo reviewer who simply see "YOU TOUCHED CODE, NO, BAD!" without reading.... I honestly think this edit was appropriate.

Comment: What I thought was that one of them marked as "deviates from intent" and the other two just 'chimed in' without looking properly.

Comment: @cst1992 The SE queue tends to REJECT!!!!!1111one  edits that touch code significantly without second look.

Comment: @Magisch So I shouldn't reissue the edit? I'm not a fan of seeing "Your last edit was rejected" banners when making edits.

Comment: @cst1992 you probably should not.

Comment: @gnat My question is broader - if I feel some work on a post is unfinished and can be finished with an edit, should I go ahead and do the edit?

Comment: @cst1992 Generally speaking, you should not edit if a) your edit could easily be your own answer, b) it could be a comment instead or c) your edit could fix (mask) errors that are relevant in the question. In this case neither was the case. I think your edit was wrongfully rejected, so I went ahead and submitted it for the question you linked.

Answer (score 2):

Improve posts by editing or commenting

> Our goal is to have the best answers to every question, so if you see
>   questions or answers that can be improved, you can edit them.
>
> Use edits to fix mistakes, improve formatting, or clarify the meaning
>   of a post.

When should I edit posts?

> Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to
>   suggest an edit, you are welcome to do so. The original author of a
>   question or answer may always edit their own post, regardless of
>   reputation level.
>
> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than
>   you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> To fix grammar and spelling mistakes To clarify the meaning of the
>   post (without changing that meaning) To include additional information
>   only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post
>   is contained in one place To correct minor mistakes or add updates as
>   the post ages To add related resources or hyperlinks

[When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code)

Comment: This post needs to be edited for formatting.